# Scrape POST data with hhb_curl

Tags: php, curl

I like to thank hanshenrik for his excellent work on [Scraping data with POST data in PHP from ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929939/scraping-data-with-post-data-in-php-from-asp-net)

I tried the same code, unfortunately not working.I guess something has changed recently its not working??? any help to fetch the results will be helpful.

```
$registration_number='R23CCP';
$vehicle_maker='CITROEN';


$ch=hhb_curl_init();

$debugHeaders=array();
$debugCookies=array();
$debugRequest='';

$html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch,'https://www.vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/Default.aspx',$debugHeaders,$debugCookies,$debugRequest);
//first do an empty request to get a session id and cookies and the weird VIEWSTATE stuff...
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
assert(is_object($domd));
$__VIEWSTATE=$domd->getElementById('__VIEWSTATE')->getAttribute('value');
$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=$domd->getElementById('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')->getAttribute('value');
$__EVENTVALIDATION=$domd->getElementById('__EVENTVALIDATION')->getAttribute('value');

var_dump('__VIEWSTATE:',$__VIEWSTATE,'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:',$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,'__EVENTVALIDATION:',$__EVENTVALIDATION,'headers:',$debugHeaders,'cookies:',$debugCookies,'html:',$html,'request:',$debugRequest,'domd:',$domd);

//now to get the POST stuff
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_POST=>true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>http_build_query(array(
'__LASTFOCUS'=>'',
'__EVENTTARGET'=>'',
'__VIEWSTATE'=>$__VIEWSTATE,
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'=>$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
'__EVENTVALIDATION'=>$__EVENTVALIDATION,
'ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchVrm'=>$registration_number,
'ctl00$MainContent$MakeTextBox'=>$vehicle_maker,
'ctl00$MainContent$txtV5CDocumentReferenceNumber'=>'',
'ctl00$MainContent$butSearch'=>'Search',
))
));
$html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch,'https://www.vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/Default.aspx',$debugHeaders,$debugCookies,$debugRequest);
var_dump('headers:',$debugHeaders,'cookies:',$debugCookies,'html:',$html,'request:',$debugRequest);


function hhb_curl_init($custom_options_array = array())
{
if (empty($custom_options_array)) {
$custom_options_array = array();
//i feel kinda bad about this.. argv[1] of curl_init wants a string(url), or NULL
//at least i want to allow NULL aswell :/
}
if (!is_array($custom_options_array)) {
throw new InvalidArgumentException('$custom_options_array must be an array!');
}
;
$options_array = array(
CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => false,
CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 11,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => ""
//CURLOPT_REFERER=>'example.org',
//CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'
);
if (!array_key_exists(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $custom_options_array)) {
//do this only conditionally because tmpfile() call..
static $curl_cookiefiles_arr = array(); //workaround for https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66014
$curl_cookiefiles_arr[]            = $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = tmpfile();
$options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = stream_get_meta_data($options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE]);
$options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE]['uri'];

}
//we can't use array_merge() because of how it handles integer-keys, it would/could cause corruption
foreach ($custom_options_array as $key => $val) {
$options_array[$key] = $val;
}
unset($key, $val, $custom_options_array);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options_array);
return $curl;
}
function hhb_curl_exec($ch, $url)
{
static $hhb_curl_domainCache = "";
//$hhb_curl_domainCache=&$this->hhb_curl_domainCache;
//$ch=&$this->curlh;
if (!is_resource($ch) || get_resource_type($ch) !== 'curl') {
throw new InvalidArgumentException('$ch must be a curl handle!');
}
if (!is_string($url)) {
throw new InvalidArgumentException('$url must be a string!');
}

$tmpvar = "";
if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) === null) {
if (substr($url, 0, 1) !== '/') {
$url = $hhb_curl_domainCache . '/' . $url;
} else {
$url = $hhb_curl_domainCache . $url;
}
}
;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
throw new Exception('Curl error (curl_errno=' . curl_errno($ch) . ') on url ' . var_export($url, true) . ': ' . curl_error($ch));
// echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
if ($html === '' && 203 != ($tmpvar = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) /*203 is "success, but no output"..*/ ) {
throw new Exception('Curl returned nothing for ' . var_export($url, true) . ' but HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE was ' . var_export($tmpvar, true));
}
;
//remember that curl (usually) auto-follows the "Location: " http redirects..
$hhb_curl_domainCache = parse_url(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL), PHP_URL_HOST);
return $html;
}
function hhb_curl_exec2($ch, $url, &$returnHeaders = array(), &$returnCookies = array(), &$verboseDebugInfo = "")
{
$returnHeaders    = array();
$returnCookies    = array();
$verboseDebugInfo = "";
if (!is_resource($ch) || get_resource_type($ch) !== 'curl') {
throw new InvalidArgumentException('$ch must be a curl handle!');
}
if (!is_string($url)) {
throw new InvalidArgumentException('$url must be a string!');
}
$verbosefileh = tmpfile();
$verbosefile  = stream_get_meta_data($verbosefileh);
$verbosefile  = $verbosefile['uri'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbosefileh);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$html             = hhb_curl_exec($ch, $url);
$verboseDebugInfo = file_get_contents($verbosefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, NULL);
fclose($verbosefileh);
unset($verbosefile, $verbosefileh);
$headers       = array();
$crlf          = "\x0d\x0a";
$thepos        = strpos($html, $crlf . $crlf, 0);
$headersString = substr($html, 0, $thepos);
$headerArr     = explode($crlf, $headersString);
$returnHeaders = $headerArr;
unset($headersString, $headerArr);
$htmlBody = substr($html, $thepos + 4); //should work on utf8/ascii headers... utf32? not so sure..
unset($html);
//I REALLY HOPE THERE EXIST A BETTER WAY TO GET COOKIES.. good grief this looks ugly..
//at least it's tested and seems to work perfectly...
$grabCookieName = function($str,&$len)
{
$len=0;
$ret = "";
$i   = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); ++$i) {
++$len;
if ($str[$i] === ' ') {
continue;
}
if ($str[$i] === '=') {
--$len;
break;
}
$ret .= $str[$i];
}
return urldecode($ret);
};
foreach ($returnHeaders as $header) {
//Set-Cookie: crlfcoookielol=crlf+is%0D%0A+and+newline+is+%0D%0A+and+semicolon+is%3B+and+not+sure+what+else
/*Set-Cookie:ci_spill=a%3A4%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22305d3d67b8016ca9661c3b032d4319df%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A14%3A%2285.164.158.128%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A109%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F43.0.2357.132+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1436874639%3B%7Dcab1dd09f4eca466660e8a767856d013; expires=Tue, 14-Jul-2015 13:50:39 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: sessionToken=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT;
//Cookie names cannot contain any of the following '=,; \t\r\n\013\014'
//
*/
if (stripos($header, "Set-Cookie:") !== 0) {
continue;
/**/
}
$header = trim(substr($header, strlen("Set-Cookie:")));
$len=0;
while (strlen($header) > 0) {
$cookiename                 = $grabCookieName($header,$len);
$returnCookies[$cookiename] = '';
$header                     = substr($header, $len + 1); //also remove the = 
if (strlen($header) < 1) {
break;
}
;
$thepos = strpos($header, ';');
if ($thepos === false) { //last cookie in this Set-Cookie.
$returnCookies[$cookiename] = urldecode($header);
break;
}
$returnCookies[$cookiename] = urldecode(substr($header, 0, $thepos));
$header                     = trim(substr($header, $thepos + 1)); //also remove the ;
}
}
unset($header, $cookiename, $thepos);
return $htmlBody;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `unfortunately not working`. Too broad. Describe in detail what error you get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex, I used this php code to fetch the results page of https://www.vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/Default.aspx with entering "R23CCP" as registration number and make "CITROEN".... response i am getting doesnt meet the actual response page? any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Remove the www. from all the URL's

Pavel Petrov just answered this for me on another post.

[Curl Post - server not returning response DVLA scraping ASPx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948088/curl-post-server-not-returning-response-dvla-scraping-aspx)