# Curl Post - server not returning response DVLA scraping ASPx

Tags: php, curl

I have previously been using the following cURL script to use data from the DVLA website to assist with data implemenation on mysite. I apologise that I cannot point to the original source of the code as I got it from this site and failed to note the source.

```html
function hhb_curl_exec($ch, $url)
{
    static $hhb_curl_domainCache = "";
    //$hhb_curl_domainCache=&$this->hhb_curl_domainCache;
    //$ch=&$this->curlh;
    if (!is_resource($ch) || get_resource_type($ch) !== 'curl') {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$ch must be a curl handle!');
    }
    if (!is_string($url)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$url must be a string!');
    }

    $tmpvar = "";
    if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) === null) {
        if (substr($url, 0, 1) !== '/') {
            $url = $hhb_curl_domainCache . '/' . $url;
        } else {
            $url = $hhb_curl_domainCache . $url;
        }
    }
    ;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        throw new Exception('Curl error (curl_errno=' . curl_errno($ch) . ') on url ' . var_export($url, true) . ': ' . curl_error($ch));
        // echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    if ($html === '' && 203 != ($tmpvar = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) /*203 is "success, but no output"..*/ ) {
        throw new Exception('Curl returned nothing for ' . var_export($url, true) . ' but HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE was ' . var_export($tmpvar, true));
    }
    ;
    //remember that curl (usually) auto-follows the "Location: " http redirects..
    $hhb_curl_domainCache = parse_url(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL), PHP_URL_HOST);
    return $html;
}
function hhb_curl_exec2($ch, $url, &$returnHeaders = array(), &$returnCookies = array(), &$verboseDebugInfo = "")
{
    $returnHeaders    = array();
    $returnCookies    = array();
    $verboseDebugInfo = "";
    if (!is_resource($ch) || get_resource_type($ch) !== 'curl') {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$ch must be a curl handle!');
    }
    if (!is_string($url)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$url must be a string!');
    }
    $verbosefileh = tmpfile();
    $verbosefile  = stream_get_meta_data($verbosefileh);
    $verbosefile  = $verbosefile['uri'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbosefileh);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $html             = hhb_curl_exec($ch, $url);
    $verboseDebugInfo = file_get_contents($verbosefile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, NULL);
    fclose($verbosefileh);
    unset($verbosefile, $verbosefileh);
    $headers       = array();
    $crlf          = "\x0d\x0a";
    $thepos        = strpos($html, $crlf . $crlf, 0);
    $headersString = substr($html, 0, $thepos);
    $headerArr     = explode($crlf, $headersString);
    $returnHeaders = $headerArr;
    unset($headersString, $headerArr);
    $htmlBody = substr($html, $thepos + 4); //should work on utf8/ascii headers... utf32? not so sure..
    unset($html);
    //I REALLY HOPE THERE EXIST A BETTER WAY TO GET COOKIES.. good grief this looks ugly..
    //at least it's tested and seems to work perfectly...
    $grabCookieName = function($str,&$len)
    {
        $len=0;
        $ret = "";
        $i   = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); ++$i) {
            ++$len;
            if ($str[$i] === ' ') {
                continue;
            }
            if ($str[$i] === '=') {
                --$len;
                break;
            }
            $ret .= $str[$i];
        }
        return urldecode($ret);
    };
    foreach ($returnHeaders as $header) {
        //Set-Cookie: crlfcoookielol=crlf+is%0D%0A+and+newline+is+%0D%0A+and+semicolon+is%3B+and+not+sure+what+else
        /*Set-Cookie:ci_spill=a%3A4%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22305d3d67b8016ca9661c3b032d4319df%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A14%3A%2285.164.158.128%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A109%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F43.0.2357.132+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1436874639%3B%7Dcab1dd09f4eca466660e8a767856d013; expires=Tue, 14-Jul-2015 13:50:39 GMT; path=/
        Set-Cookie: sessionToken=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT;
        //Cookie names cannot contain any of the following '=,; \t\r\n\013\014'
        //
        */
        if (stripos($header, "Set-Cookie:") !== 0) {
            continue;
            /**/
        }
        $header = trim(substr($header, strlen("Set-Cookie:")));
        $len=0;
        while (strlen($header) > 0) {
            $cookiename                 = $grabCookieName($header,$len);
            $returnCookies[$cookiename] = '';
            $header                     = substr($header, $len + 1); //also remove the = 
            if (strlen($header) < 1) {
                break;
            }
            ;
            $thepos = strpos($header, ';');
            if ($thepos === false) { //last cookie in this Set-Cookie.
                $returnCookies[$cookiename] = urldecode($header);
                break;
            }
            $returnCookies[$cookiename] = urldecode(substr($header, 0, $thepos));
            $header                     = trim(substr($header, $thepos + 1)); //also remove the ;
        }
    }
    unset($header, $cookiename, $thepos);
    return $htmlBody;
}

##############################################################
function hhb_curl_init($custom_options_array = array())
{
    if (empty($custom_options_array)) {
        $custom_options_array = array();
        //i feel kinda bad about this.. argv[1] of curl_init wants a string(url), or NULL
        //at least i want to allow NULL aswell :/
    }
    if (!is_array($custom_options_array)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$custom_options_array must be an array!');
    }
    ;
    $options_array = array(
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 11,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => ""
        //CURLOPT_REFERER=>'example.org',
        //CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'
    );
    if (!array_key_exists(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $custom_options_array)) {
        //do this only conditionally because tmpfile() call..
        static $curl_cookiefiles_arr = array(); //workaround for https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66014
        $curl_cookiefiles_arr[]            = $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = tmpfile();
        $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = stream_get_meta_data($options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE]);
        $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE]['uri'];

    }
    //we can't use array_merge() because of how it handles integer-keys, it would/could cause corruption
    foreach ($custom_options_array as $key => $val) {
        $options_array[$key] = $val;
    }
    unset($key, $val, $custom_options_array);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options_array);
    return $curl;
}




//------------------------------------------------//

//Registration and VRM have to be valid and make as per the DVLA format for makes otehrwise this wont work!

$registration_number = 'PK07LVD'; // must be a valid VRM to get the correct response
$vehicle_maker ='BMW'; //Make must matchVRM held with DVLA and entered in same format as DVLA list on site


$ch=hhb_curl_init();

$debugHeaders=array();
$debugCookies=array();
$debugRequest='';

$html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch,'https://www.vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/Default.aspx',$debugHeaders,$debugCookies,$debugRequest);
//first do an empty request to get a session id and cookies and the weird VIEWSTATE stuff...
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
assert(is_object($domd));
$__VIEWSTATE=$domd->getElementById('__VIEWSTATE')->getAttribute('value');
$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=$domd->getElementById('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')->getAttribute('value');
$__EVENTVALIDATION=$domd->getElementById('__EVENTVALIDATION')->getAttribute('value');

//var_dump('__VIEWSTATE:',$__VIEWSTATE,'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:',$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,'__EVENTVALIDATION:',$__EVENTVALIDATION,'headers:',$debugHeaders,'cookies:',$debugCookies,'html:',$html,'request:',$debugRequest,'domd:',$domd);

//now to get the POST stuff
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_POST=>true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>http_build_query(array(
'__LASTFOCUS'=>'',
'__EVENTTARGET'=>'',
'__VIEWSTATE'=>$__VIEWSTATE,
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'=>$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
'__EVENTVALIDATION'=>$__EVENTVALIDATION,
'ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchVrm'=>'$registration_number',
'ctl00$MainContent$MakeTextBox'=>'$vehicle_maker',
'ctl00$MainContent$txtV5CDocumentReferenceNumber'=>'',
'ctl00$MainContent$butSearch'=>'Search',
))
));


$html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch,'https://www.vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/Default.aspx',$debugHeaders,$debugCookies,$debugRequest);
//var_dump('headers:',$debugHeaders,'cookies:',$debugCookies,'html:',$html,'request:',$debugRequest);

echo $html;

?>
```

For some reason over the last week something has changed and I am not getting a result being returned in $html, all that is happening is the form to enter the Vehicle registration and Make is being displayed.

The variables that the enquiry form is sending are:

```html
Array
(
    [__EVENTTARGET] => 
    [__EVENTARGUMENT] => 
    [__VIEWSTATE] => 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
    [__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR] => CA0B0334
    [__EVENTVALIDATION] => /wEdAAec98WnAVQeQUdqU6NI4oVRBOwywjxOOgpEYFN2beEgnftoCCZcWJSqSRLD/FKuxxkI0x5r4gPeKgWgSNWptTEWInv2PXI3Jzdn3U6eHDG4Qb7lltCXTdtnDbitYujbDJI0GQSIMiv32DreL6oRbYpQ8QTO8WJr3q5Y80Jf5PzdZW5VzdA=
    [ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchVrm] => pk07lvd
    [ctl00$MainContent$MakeTextBox] => bmw
    [ctl00$MainContent$txtV5CDocumentReferenceNumber] => 
    [ctl00$MainContent$butSearch] => Search
)
```

When I run the form remotely from my server and have the form POST the variables to https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/, I do get the required result being returned, but obviously being displayed on the browers through the Goverment website.

I am looking for help as to what is possibly going on, or has gone wrong with the code. Pulling my hair out trying to investigate each stage as to why, when I run the cURL coding, I am not getting the result returned in $html, but just the initial enquiry form.

I would be grateful for any assitance. I know there was a similar post, but with less detail as to what had been done to investigate the issue. Due to being new the site said I couldnt reply.

//-------------------Edit from original code added 09/10/16 21:46 -----------------//

This code forms part of another function. I have since removed the overriding function for clarity.

//--------------------------- Regarding output----------//

In a sense this code does work as $html always outputs a response from the vehicle enquiry service..

The issue is that the remote site is (https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk) does not seem to be processing the POST data and returning the result of the query. All that is returned is the initial enquiry form as though you had not entered any form data.

---

I would expect $html to contain a response with vehicle details, tax, mot status:

Instead the cURL command responds with the enquiry form being returned.

Comment: How do you run this thing? :)

Comment: The function dvlascrape($send_array) doesn't actually use anything from the parameters, so parameter is useless.

When I run that function I get no error from curl and receive some html, doesn't look too right but I do receive html.

What do you see when you add var_dump(curl_error ( $ch )) ; before return $html;?

Comment: Yes sorry about the dvlascrape($send_array) function. This code formed part of another operation to whihc this is a function of it.

Comment: So as a stand alone code

Comment: Found the bugs I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First mistake:**

```
'ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchVrm'=>'$registration_number',
'ctl00$MainContent$MakeTextBox'=>'$vehicle_maker',
```

Should be:

```
'ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchVrm'=>$registration_number,
'ctl00$MainContent$MakeTextBox'=>$vehicle_maker,
```

**Second mistake**

```
$html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch,'https://www.vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/Default.aspx',$debugHeaders,$debugCookies,$debugRequest);
```

Should be:

```
$html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch,'https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/Default.aspx',$debugHeaders,$debugCookies,$debugRequest);
```

**Whole code:**

```
<?php
function dvlascrape($send_array)
{

$make_trimmed=$send_array['2'];
$vrm_strip=$send_array['0'];



function hhb_curl_exec($ch, $url)
{
    static $hhb_curl_domainCache = "";
    //$hhb_curl_domainCache=&$this->hhb_curl_domainCache;
    //$ch=&$this->curlh;
    if (!is_resource($ch) || get_resource_type($ch) !== 'curl') {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$ch must be a curl handle!');
    }
    if (!is_string($url)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$url must be a string!');
    }

    $tmpvar = "";
    if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) === null) {
        if (substr($url, 0, 1) !== '/') {
            $url = $hhb_curl_domainCache . '/' . $url;
        } else {
            $url = $hhb_curl_domainCache . $url;
        }
    }
    ;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        throw new Exception('Curl error (curl_errno=' . curl_errno($ch) . ') on url ' . var_export($url, true) . ': ' . curl_error($ch));
        // echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    if ($html === '' && 203 != ($tmpvar = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) /*203 is "success, but no output"..*/ ) {
        throw new Exception('Curl returned nothing for ' . var_export($url, true) . ' but HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE was ' . var_export($tmpvar, true));
    }
    ;
    //remember that curl (usually) auto-follows the "Location: " http redirects..
    $hhb_curl_domainCache = parse_url(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL), PHP_URL_HOST);
    return $html;
}
function hhb_curl_exec2($ch, $url, &$returnHeaders = array(), &$returnCookies = array(), &$verboseDebugInfo = "")
{
    $returnHeaders    = array();
    $returnCookies    = array();
    $verboseDebugInfo = "";
    if (!is_resource($ch) || get_resource_type($ch) !== 'curl') {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$ch must be a curl handle!');
    }
    if (!is_string($url)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$url must be a string!');
    }
    $verbosefileh = tmpfile();
    $verbosefile  = stream_get_meta_data($verbosefileh);
    $verbosefile  = $verbosefile['uri'];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbosefileh);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $html             = hhb_curl_exec($ch, $url);
    $verboseDebugInfo = file_get_contents($verbosefile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, NULL);
    fclose($verbosefileh);
    unset($verbosefile, $verbosefileh);
    $headers       = array();
    $crlf          = "\x0d\x0a";
    $thepos        = strpos($html, $crlf . $crlf, 0);
    $headersString = substr($html, 0, $thepos);
    $headerArr     = explode($crlf, $headersString);
    $returnHeaders = $headerArr;
    unset($headersString, $headerArr);
    $htmlBody = substr($html, $thepos + 4); //should work on utf8/ascii headers... utf32? not so sure..
    unset($html);
    //I REALLY HOPE THERE EXIST A BETTER WAY TO GET COOKIES.. good grief this looks ugly..
    //at least it's tested and seems to work perfectly...
    $grabCookieName = function($str,&$len)
    {
        $len=0;
        $ret = "";
        $i   = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); ++$i) {
            ++$len;
            if ($str[$i] === ' ') {
                continue;
            }
            if ($str[$i] === '=') {
                --$len;
                break;
            }
            $ret .= $str[$i];
        }
        return urldecode($ret);
    };
    foreach ($returnHeaders as $header) {
        //Set-Cookie: crlfcoookielol=crlf+is%0D%0A+and+newline+is+%0D%0A+and+semicolon+is%3B+and+not+sure+what+else
        /*Set-Cookie:ci_spill=a%3A4%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22305d3d67b8016ca9661c3b032d4319df%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A14%3A%2285.164.158.128%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A109%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F43.0.2357.132+Safari%2F537.36%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1436874639%3B%7Dcab1dd09f4eca466660e8a767856d013; expires=Tue, 14-Jul-2015 13:50:39 GMT; path=/
        Set-Cookie: sessionToken=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT;
        //Cookie names cannot contain any of the following '=,; \t\r\n\013\014'
        //
        */
        if (stripos($header, "Set-Cookie:") !== 0) {
            continue;
            /**/
        }
        $header = trim(substr($header, strlen("Set-Cookie:")));
        $len=0;
        while (strlen($header) > 0) {
            $cookiename                 = $grabCookieName($header,$len);
            $returnCookies[$cookiename] = '';
            $header                     = substr($header, $len + 1); //also remove the =
            if (strlen($header) < 1) {
                break;
            }
            ;
            $thepos = strpos($header, ';');
            if ($thepos === false) { //last cookie in this Set-Cookie.
                $returnCookies[$cookiename] = urldecode($header);
                break;
            }
            $returnCookies[$cookiename] = urldecode(substr($header, 0, $thepos));
            $header                     = trim(substr($header, $thepos + 1)); //also remove the ;
        }
    }
    unset($header, $cookiename, $thepos);
    return $htmlBody;
}

##############################################################
function hhb_curl_init($custom_options_array = array())
{
    if (empty($custom_options_array)) {
        $custom_options_array = array();
        //i feel kinda bad about this.. argv[1] of curl_init wants a string(url), or NULL
        //at least i want to allow NULL aswell :/
    }
    if (!is_array($custom_options_array)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$custom_options_array must be an array!');
    }
    ;
    $options_array = array(
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 11,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => ""
        //CURLOPT_REFERER=>'example.org',
        //CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0'
    );
    if (!array_key_exists(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $custom_options_array)) {
        //do this only conditionally because tmpfile() call..
        static $curl_cookiefiles_arr = array(); //workaround for https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66014
        $curl_cookiefiles_arr[]            = $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = tmpfile();
        $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = stream_get_meta_data($options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE]);
        $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE] = $options_array[CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE]['uri'];

    }
    //we can't use array_merge() because of how it handles integer-keys, it would/could cause corruption
    foreach ($custom_options_array as $key => $val) {
        $options_array[$key] = $val;
    }
    unset($key, $val, $custom_options_array);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options_array);
    return $curl;
}




//------------------------------------------------//

//Registration and VRM have to be valid and make as per the DVLA format for makes otehrwise this wont work!

$registration_number = 'PK07LVD'; // must be a valid VRM to get the correct response
$vehicle_maker ='BMW'; //Make must matchVRM held with DVLA and entered in same format as DVLA list on site


$ch=hhb_curl_init();

$debugHeaders=array();
$debugCookies=array();
$debugRequest='';

$html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch,'https://www.vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/Default.aspx',$debugHeaders,$debugCookies,$debugRequest);
//first do an empty request to get a session id and cookies and the weird VIEWSTATE stuff...
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
assert(is_object($domd));
$__VIEWSTATE=$domd->getElementById('__VIEWSTATE')->getAttribute('value');
$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=$domd->getElementById('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR')->getAttribute('value');
$__EVENTVALIDATION=$domd->getElementById('__EVENTVALIDATION')->getAttribute('value');

//var_dump('__VIEWSTATE:',$__VIEWSTATE,'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:',$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,'__EVENTVALIDATION:',$__EVENTVALIDATION,'headers:',$debugHeaders,'cookies:',$debugCookies,'html:',$html,'request:',$debugRequest,'domd:',$domd);
var_dump($__VIEWSTATE);
//now to get the POST stuff
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_POST=>true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>http_build_query(array(
'__LASTFOCUS'=>'',
'__EVENTTARGET'=>'',
'__EVENTARGUMENT'=>'',
'__VIEWSTATE'=>$__VIEWSTATE,
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'=>$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
'__EVENTVALIDATION'=>$__EVENTVALIDATION,
'ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchVrm'=>$registration_number,
'ctl00$MainContent$MakeTextBox'=>$vehicle_maker,
'ctl00$MainContent$txtV5CDocumentReferenceNumber'=>'',
'ctl00$MainContent$butSearch'=>'Search',
))
));
var_dump(
array(
'__LASTFOCUS'=>'',
'__EVENTTARGET'=>'',
'__EVENTARGUMENT'=>'',
'__VIEWSTATE'=>$__VIEWSTATE,
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'=>$__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
'__EVENTVALIDATION'=>$__EVENTVALIDATION,
'ctl00$MainContent$txtSearchVrm'=>$registration_number,
'ctl00$MainContent$MakeTextBox'=>$vehicle_maker,
'ctl00$MainContent$txtV5CDocumentReferenceNumber'=>'',
'ctl00$MainContent$butSearch'=>'Search',
));

$html=hhb_curl_exec2($ch,'https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/Default.aspx',$debugHeaders,$debugCookies,$debugRequest);
//var_dump(curl_error ( $ch )) ;
//var_dump('headers:',$debugHeaders,'cookies:',$debugCookies,'html:',$html,'request:',$debugRequest);

return $html;






}

var_dump(dvlascrape(array('', '', '')));
?>
```

Comment: Excellent - Thank you Pavel.... I cannot believe it is always the most simple things I did not notice.

Comment: This same code did work but a few weeks ago so they must have changed their site address to remove the www.

Sometimes you cannot see the wood for the trees. 

Once again. Thank you very much :D

Comment: is there a working example to the latest update?  The new url is https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ViewVehicle